# TVertScrollBox in Delphi XE6 FireMonkey is very, very slow. Fix?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I am currently building a FireMonkey App for Android.
I have a function that gets a number out of the database, and using that number, it generates the same amount of rectangles. These rectangles are added into a TGridLayout. Right now I have close to 60 rectangles generated, and the TVertScrollBox works unresponsive, slow and choppy. Is there any way to implement another way of scrolling into my app? Or something to fix this slow and unresponsive scrolling?

Comment: I've noticed scrolling in general anywhere in Firemonkey is slow and choppy, including `TListBox` with just 20 items in it.

Comment: @JerryDodge hmm. Interesting. Whenever I use a TListView, it works perfectly fine and smooth.

Comment: Well I don't know about Android, but I've seen that in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize [TImageCacheLayout](http://www.fmxexpress.com/speed-up-your-apps-with-bitmap-caching-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/) to cache your components as bitmaps. Should increase speed. The slow scrolling of a TListBox with a lot of components on Android is fixed in Delphi XE8.